# Vue strap popover error

Tags: vuejs2, vue-strap

I have the following view:

```
<div id="root" class="container">
    <template>
        <popover trigger="hover" effect="fade" placement="top" title="Title">
            <button class="btn btn-default">Popover on bottom</button>
        </popover>
    </template>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.3/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="lesson.js"> </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-strap/1.1.37/vue-strap.min.js"></script>
```

My lesson.js file looks the following:

new Vue({
    el: "#root",

```
data: {
    content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod',
},

components: {
    popover: VueStrap.popover
},
```

});

But then I got the following error:

```
 [Vue warn]: failed to compile template:

    <span v-el:trigger> <slot></slot> <div v-el:popover v-if=show 
:class="['popover',placement]" :transition=effect> 
<div class=arrow></div> <h3 class=popover-title v-if=title> 
<slot name=title>{{title}}</slot> 
</h3> <div class=popover-content> <slot name=content>{{{content}}}</slot> 
</div> </div> </span>

    - invalid expression: {{{content}}}


    (found in component <popover>)
```

pls, help

Answer (score 1):

It is compiling error

```
<slot name=content>{{{content}}}</slot>
```

**Edited**

And this error is in [source](https://github.com/yuche/vue-strap/blob/master/src/Popover.vue) of component

Comment: Is it possible to give a working example of vue strap popup, cause I don't even have "content" section here and it still doesn't work.

Comment: this error is in the [source](https://github.com/yuche/vue-strap/blob/master/src/Popover.vue) of popover line 13. I created [issue](https://github.com/yuche/vue-strap/issues/476) for it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is another version of vue bootstrap which works without errors:
https://bootstrap-vue.github.io/docs/setup/